# Glide File Not Found Exception from Firebase Database

Tags: android, firebase, android-glide

I am using the Glide library to download images saved on my firebase real-time database. I can see the images and caption text uploaded from my app to the DB, however, it's not downloading the images in the recycler view of the app but is showing the text from the DB. When i hardcoded the glide method with the URL of the image its showing in the app but not able to download from the code Glide.with(context).load((UploadInfo.getImageURL())).into(holder.imageView);.

I'm using Samsung 2016 Galaxy A5 phone for testing. Tried restarting and clean build in the studio.

//Error Logs

```
2019-04-24 01:14:04.748 6713-6713/com.xyz W/Glide: Load failed for com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzu@7b60e with size [1080x600]
    class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Failed to load resource
    There were 3 causes:
    java.io.FileNotFoundException(/com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzu@7b60e (No such file or directory))
    java.io.FileNotFoundException(No such file or directory)
    java.io.FileNotFoundException(No such file or directory)
     call GlideException#logRootCauses(String) for more detail
      Cause (1 of 3): class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Fetching data failed, class java.io.InputStream, LOCAL
    There was 1 cause:
    java.io.FileNotFoundException(/com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzu@7b60d5e (No such file or directory))
     call GlideException#logRootCauses(String) for more detail
        Cause (1 of 1): class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Fetch failed
    There was 1 cause:
    java.io.FileNotFoundException(/com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzu@7b60e (No such file or directory))
     call GlideException#logRootCauses(String) for more detail
          Cause (1 of 1): class java.io.FileNotFoundException: /com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzu@7b60d5e (No such file or directory)
      Cause (2 of 3): class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Fetching data failed, class android.os.ParcelFileDescriptor, LOCAL
    There was 1 cause:
    java.io.FileNotFoundException(No such file or directory)
     call GlideException#logRootCauses(String) for more detail
        Cause (1 of 1): class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Fetch failed
    There was 1 cause:
    java.io.FileNotFoundException(No such file or directory)
     call GlideException#logRootCauses(String) for more detail
          Cause (1 of 1): class java.io.FileNotFoundException: No such file or directory
      Cause (3 of 3): class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Fetching data failed, class android.content.res.AssetFileDescriptor, LOCAL
    There was 1 cause:
    java.io.FileNotFoundException(No such file or directory)
     call GlideException#logRootCauses(String) for more detail
        Cause (1 of 1): class java.io.FileNotFoundException: No such file or directory


//Glide method in the below class
public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    public static Context context;
    List<ImageUploadInfo> MainImageUploadInfoList;

    public RecyclerViewAdapter(Context context, List<ImageUploadInfo> TempList) {

        this.MainImageUploadInfoList = TempList;

        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.activity_recycler_view_adapter, parent, false);

        ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(view);

        return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        ImageUploadInfo UploadInfo = MainImageUploadInfoList.get(position);

        holder.imageNameTextView.setText(UploadInfo.getImageName());

        //Loading image from Glide library.

        Glide.with(context).load((UploadInfo.getImageURL())).into(holder.imageView);
        //Glide.with(context).load("com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzu@7b60e").into(holder.imageView);
        //Glide.with(context).load("https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/xyz-d840c.appspot.com/o/All_Image_Uploads%2F1555878624050.jpg?alt=media&token=3b04e084-55bf-4693-9c57-db77bffaa0e8").into(holder.imageView);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {

        return MainImageUploadInfoList.size();
    }

    class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        public ImageView imageView;
        public TextView imageNameTextView;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            imageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);

            imageNameTextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.ImageNameTextView);
        }
    }
}


//Gradle app file

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.xyz"
        minSdkVersion 24
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE-FIREBASE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'

    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'

    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.8'

    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:16.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.2.1'
    implementation 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.4.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.1.0'
    //For Gallery Images
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.9.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.9.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0'
    implementation 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.4.+'
    implementation 'id.zelory:compressor:2.0.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.5.0'


    //https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android
    // FirebaseUI for Firebase Realtime Database
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:4.3.2'

    // FirebaseUI for Cloud Firestore
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-firestore:4.3.2'

    // FirebaseUI for Firebase Auth
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:4.3.2'

    // FirebaseUI for Firebase Auth (GitHub provider)
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth-github:4.3.2'

    // FirebaseUI for Cloud Storage
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-storage:4.3.2'

    //implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:16.4.0'

    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:16.0.1'
    //implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:jar:12.0.1'
    //implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:12.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.6.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: first try to print image url in logs and load it in browser and check files exist or not

Comment: Please add the code the produces this error and your database structure.

Answer (score 1):

```
implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
```

Add given library in your Gradle and sync the project

```
 Picasso.get().load(UploadInfo.getImageURL()).error(R.drawable.ic_errorwhite_24dp).into(holder.imageView);
```

use `Picasso` instead of `Glide`, it will automatically catch the error

Comment: I changed the method like you suggested, in the app its now showing me the the error image from drawable folder mentioned in the picasso method. Its really strange that i'm able to get the text that i uploaded but not the image.@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        ImageUploadInfo UploadInfo = MainImageUploadInfoList.get(position);

 holder.imageNameTextView.setText(UploadInfo.getImageName());    Picasso.with(context).load(UploadInfo.getImageURL()).error(R.drawable.default_avatar).into(holder.imageView);  }